# How can I get an NES controller to work on my PC as a Joystick?

Tags: pc, controllers, nes, snes

I want to be able to use an actual NES (or, SNES) controller to control an emulator on my PC.

*Is this possible?*

If so, how can I do this *on a budget*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

RetroZone has [a product](http://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=21&products_id=28) which adds a NES port to your computer via USB. Also, you could buy an [already converted NES](http://www.retrousb.com/product_info.php?cPath=21&products_id=32) controller which plugs directly into your USB port. (They also supply the same products for SNES.)

As for converting a controller yourself, Joystiq has [a tutorial](http://www.joystiq.com/2004/09/07/how-to-make-a-nintendo-controller-into-a-pc-joystick/) but it involves buying a kit from RetroZone.

Comment: There are actually a lot of USB-to-controller adapters, for every popular console controller. They've been around for years.

Comment: A friend of mine in college spliced the wires to an old serial port cord directly o_o Not sure how he got it to pick up on the comp as a joystick