# Is there any electronic board map to convert PlayStation or XBox joy-stick to PC?

Tags: xbox-360, pc, hardware

My fiend says: search and google and find electronic map board to make an electronic board to convert PS or XBox Joystick and connect to PC.

- electronic board map
- drivers

[image: electronic board map]

Comment: And what did Googling that find you? (I can't tell if this is a novel kind of spamming to get answerers to post the spam links they search, or if this is just a language issue + lack of using Google.)

Comment: or XBox joystick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of devices available to connect a PlayStation controller to a PC, but beyond confirming their existence I can't mention any in particular as that is off-topic for this site. My suggestion is to do a Google search for `playstation controller usb adapter`.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/464/how-can-i-get-an-nes-controller-to-work-on-my-pc-as-a-joystick

Comment: If you're going to answer at all, you might as well *answer*, y'know? :)

Comment: @Anna Yeah, but I'm not going to give a shopping-rec answer! Might as well vote to close then. (I hold the view that "does X exist?" is on-topic and shouldn't be closed as a shopping question, hence I think answering such questions with a yes/no without giving shopping advice is legit.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I wouldn't call this a shopping rec at all. Shopping rec implies, well, shopping. As in, "which joystick should I buy". Not every "I'm looking for resources" question falls into that category. If you can give a specific recommendation or perhaps describe how one might go about making this work, that's much better than just saying "google it". Heck, the whole question is basically "I should Google this", so when your answer doesn't go beyond repeating that, it doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: Mind you, I'm not sure if building boards and fiddling with drivers is on-topic to begin with. :) But assuming it is for a moment... the core of the question seems to be "how do I make a Playstation controller work with the PC". An okay answer would just list a resource or a pointer in the right direction. A great answer would actually describe how to do it.

Comment: If anything, this "answer" should be a comment... nothing more.